# How to update array of JSON data in postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```
create table test 
add column data jsonb;

insert into test values 
( 
    '[{
        "name": "Alexa", 
        "age": "20"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Siri", 
        "age": "42"
    }]' 
);
```

Table Data Looks like this:

data  <------ column_name

[{"name": "Alexa", "age": "20"}, {"name": "Siri", "age": "42"}]

I am familiar with how to update json data, Here i want to take json data from array and change it.
I want to change "name" attribute of first json object "Alexa" to "Cortana", Is it possible to do that is postgres?
P.S. This is not the actual data that I have broken down my doubt to simple problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `jsonb_set` function to return a JSON object with a section replaced with a new value

```
UPDATE test
SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{0,name}', '"Cortana"', true)
```

Comment: Thanks, can i set that to null? I did the same but it doesn’t seem to be working for null?

Comment: @AyushNaithani you should be able to pass the string `'null'` as the third parameter, what did you try?

Comment: It worked now i was writing NULL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following command also works.

```
    update test set data = data - 0 
|| jsonb_build_object('name','Cortana', 'age', '20') returning *;
```